# Edit status bar style embed viewController Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I want to edit the status bar style of my application. However, I'm unable to edit it from my main `UIViewController`. So I think multiple status bars settings are stacked because of embed `UIViewController`s.

Here is how I initiate my navigationController in the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method:

```
let navigationVC = CustomNavigationController(rootViewController: MenuInstance)
navigationVC.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: false)
```

Then, I move some views of other `UIViewController`s in the menu `UIViewController` (MenuInstance) for any reason like this:

```
let scannerVC = ScannerViewController()

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        addChildViewController(scannerVC)
        scannerVC.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
}
```

I tried to create class to set `prefersStatusBarHidden = true`

```
class ModalViewViewController: UIViewController {

    override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
        get {
            return true
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()
    }
}
```

I also created a class for the UINavigationController

```
class CustomNavigationController: UINavigationController {

    override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
        get {
            return true
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()
    }
}
```

The goal of trying to remove the status bar is to find where the status bar comes from. I want only one status bar in the MenuInstance `UIViewController` that I can edit. The fact that some views of `UIViewController`s are embed in one `UIViewController` makes me confused.

Answer (score 1):

If the MenuInstance view controller is the root view controller of the navigation controller, then the MenuInstance's implementation of `prefersStatusBarHidden` is all that matters. No other view controller's preference is consulted. The "embed" stuff is irrelevant (unless you want to make it relevant).

```
class MenuInstance : UIViewController {
    override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
        get {
            return true
        } 
    }
}
```

Note, however, that this will not work on an iPhone X. You cannot hide the status bar on an iPhone X.

Comment: Please don’t change the subject.  I answered the question you actually asked.